# What happens if you switch your git remote origin to a new repo and git pull?

Tags: git, bitbucket

The background behind my issue is that I accidentally uploaded a 5gb folder full of media files (it was actually the drupal sites/default folder which was supposed to be on the .gitignore file) to my remote repository on bitbucket. When I discovered the error, I proceeded to remove it and pushed that commit as well.

After that I realised the git history still had those files. On my local machine I did the following:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch sites/default' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
git prune
rm -rf .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

After that, I cloned this into a new local repo using:

```
git clone --no-hardlinks file://path/to/old-repo new-repo
```

which gave me a “clean” repository, with the history rewritten to remove the target folder. 
After that I changed the origin of the new repository to my bitbucket repo and force pushed the changes using:

```
git push origin master --force
```

and

```
git push origin development --force
```

Even though the commits are removed from history, and examining the source on bitbucket does not show those files at all, the repository size is still 5gb. Since I could not find a way to remove those files, I chose to create a new repository on bitbucket and pushed up my new local repository to it.

If another developer who is working on the same project changes his git remote to point to this new repository and does a git pull, will the files on his machine be the same as the new repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a colleague who was on the original repository, but as she did not pull any recent changes, was behind the commit which had the unwanted folder. After switching the origin to the new repository, the git pull was successful, with no trace of the unwanted folder in any of the commits.

Hope this helps someone who is in a similar situation.